# Dynamic Paging issue in oracle

Tags: oracle

Below is the oracle store procedure,

Here the table name i am passing is dynamic.

```
PROCEDURE LG_UTIL_GET_TABLE
(
    p_table_name VARCHAR,     
    pageNumber Number,
    pageSize Number,
        p_cursor OUT types.cursor_type
)
AS    

BEGIN

  OPEN p_cursor FOR     

  SELECT * FROM
    SELECT a.*, rownum r__

FROM
    (

        'Select * from ' || p_table_name

    ) a
    WHERE rownum < ((pageNumber * pageSize) + 1 )

WHERE r__ >= (((pageNumber-1) * pageSize) + 1)      ;



END ;
```

But the store procedure is not compiling.

because of this line,

```
Select * from ' || p_table_name
```

Instead if i use this query

```
Select * from Customer
```

, it gets compiled

but the table name should be dynamic.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing dynamic and static SQL in the same cursor, you can't do that.  Make it all dynamic like this:

```
PROCEDURE LG_UTIL_GET_TABLE
(
    p_table_name VARCHAR,     
    pageNumber Number,
    pageSize Number,
        p_cursor OUT types.cursor_type
)
AS    

BEGIN

  OPEN p_cursor FOR     

  'SELECT * FROM
    SELECT a.*, rownum r__
    FROM
    ( Select * from ' || p_table_name || ') a
    WHERE rownum < ((:pageNumber * :pageSize) + 1 )
    WHERE r__ >= (((:pageNumber-1) * :pageSize) + 1)'

    USING pageNumber, pageSize, pageNumber, pageSize;

END ;
```

Note that you now use bind variables for the values.

Comment: I believe you want `USING pageNumber, pageSize, pageNumber, pageSize` since you've got 4 bind variables in the SQL statement.